# How to make 'hadoop jar' command pick up new build of a same named jar

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm new to hadoop and I tried its example within hadoop 2.6.0 for beginning.
First, I recompiled the source code of **`hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar`** and build a new jar file **`MapReduce-0.0.1.jar`**

Then I ran the terasort example with this command line

```
jjin:hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar ~/shared/MapReduce-0.0.1.jar terasort /input /output
15/01/07 12:27:44 INFO terasort.TeraSort: starting
15/01/07 12:27:46 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
...
```

After terasort is done, I updated the source of `TeraSort.java` by modifying the first line log message like this

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
LOG.info("starting..."); 
// Update log message by adding '...' to the end of previous one.
Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());
```

But after re-run this terasort job, I found the log message didn't change to 'starting...', so it means that the change I made to `TeraSort.java` doesn't take effect.

The question is how to make hadoop pick up the new **`MapReduce-0.0.1.jar`** I build.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to recompile and re build jar and then specify different output directory other than in first job.

Comment: I renamed the package name of TeraSort and it works now.